# Библиотека Сommon.js

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Привет. Есть такая библиотека. Помогите с источниками русскоязычными.
Я даже не знаю где эту библиотеку скачать. На этом сайте [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) ничего разобрать не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не библиотека. Это сборник [стандартов](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=24478). Откуда вообще у вас возникла мысль, что это библиотека?

Answer (score 2):

Кстати, вот по [этой](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/) ссылке есть целая куча документации.

Comment: Буду смотреть эту "кучу"